# iOS 5 Push Notification - From Developing perspective

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios5

I was watching videos of **iOS 5 Push Notification** and I encountered that there are some differences in notifying User apart from Badges, Alert and Sound.

Please go through the [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWqVKvnxTSk). Here the notification of Twitter comes on the status bar. So do we need to have programming in different way than our usual push notification?

Also when we drag that view downwards than directly navigated to new Message. So how can we achieve those new changes as being a Developer?

One More question is How can we achieve the **scrolling** in Notification Window....

Comment: I don't think it's possible to put notification in status bar. Twitter can do this because it's integrated with iOS 5 - done by Apple themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the banner that sits over the status bar? That's an option your users can choose in Settings. Just push an alert as usual, and if your users have selected to display alerts as banners, that's what they'll see.

Comment: Yes that i came across and i am solved with that problem... But now i want scrolling of the Text in Notification window (one which can be dragged from top).

Answer (score 0):

No changes need to be done at developer end for viewing notifications in Notification bar or Banner. Though I have no idea how to enable scrolling in Notification Window.